# Importing Linux and Windows Dual Boot from Parallels

Tags: windows, unix, parallels-desktop, dual-boot

I am looking at triple booting my Mac soon with macOS, Linux and Windows. I also want Linux and Windows available as a virtual machine. At the moment, I have Windows dual booted and have imported it into parallels.

I will be formatting my hard drive soon and reinstall macOS on it. I will then install Linux and Windows, while using rEFInd to boot to Linux. The question is, does Parallels import only work with Windows installed via bootcamp or can it work with a triple boot system?